# Storing settings on a database

Tags: java, sql, database-design, language-agnostic

I am writing a module in my program that needs to have configured settings to run. My client has asked the settings to be **global**, company-wide. Which means that the settings need a central location (all the settings are `int`).

We do have a database storing other data, so my first idea is to just create a table on the database. But this would either involve a strictly 1-row table with very specific pre-set columns or a two-column table with each row being the setting identifier.

Basically, with my current approach, the table would either look like this:

```
Settings Table
-------------------------------------------------------
| setting_1 (int) | setting_2 (int) | setting_3 (int) |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|             440 |              7  |               0 |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

or like this:

```
Settings Table
------------------------------------------
| setting (varchar) |       value (int)  |
|-------------------|--------------------|
|       'setting_1' |                440 |
|-------------------|--------------------|
|       'setting_2' |                  7 |
|-------------------|--------------------|
|       'setting_3' |                  0 |
------------------------------------------
```

Although databases are certainly capable of doing this, in my opinion this really seems to fall outside of what databases were intended to do. I think there might be a better solution than this.

So, do you think this approach is best? Or is there a better alternative?

I'm using Java, but I could foresee language-agnostic solutions to this.

Comment: You might consider [Apache ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/). It will scale past your toy example here.

Comment: Use just a property file

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Is ZooKeeper overkill for a toy example or simple web application?

Comment: @user2310289 Probably. But if a problem is worth solving, it's worth *solving*.

Comment: That's not a universal principle when you bill by the hour, @ElliottFrisch ;) But thank you for the suggestion. ZooKeeper does look very relevant to my problem. I'll take a good look at it.

Comment: I would choose neither, because now the settings may be `INT` but you will kick yourself when the first string makes its appearance. Besides that, configuration files should be preferred over a database.

Comment: @Jack, that's exactly why I asked the question. What do you mean by "configuration files" and how would you centralize them across a network?

Comment: @Jack, with option #1 it wouldn't be a problem if they added a `String` parameter because each setting would be its own column, thus its own data type

Comment: @ryvantage All right, you've convinced me to write up my own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As much as I don't like this approach generally, your second approach - otherwise known as EVA - is the way to go for database-wide settings.

This way, whenever there is a new value (or attribute) to be added, one simply adds the row to the table with an insert table.

The first approach requires *changing the structure* of the settings table every time a new attribute is to be added, which is not a good idea.

The downside of the EVA approach is that a database access will be made for every field required (unless you want to read all the rows at once), whereas with a normal table, all the required fields can be accessed in one go. This may or may not be a problem.

Comment: As I stated to the user in the other answer. Why would changing the structure be a problem? With a 1-row dataset, a structure change would be more than manageable. Data model changes are a problem because you have to extend the changes across an existing dataset. But, if your dataset is 1 row...

Comment: Another point I made to him was that actually the first approach is BEST if there are changes, because, let's say we add a `varchar` setting. Approach 1 would make adding that setting super easy, whereas Approach 2 would require implementing types and maybe storing everything as varchar... etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's no single truth here, so it's better to write up a list of pros / cons instead:

**Option #1**

Pros:

- It's simple; all settings can be loaded in a single row.
- It's extensible; it supports multiple column types.
- It supports defaults; each column can have its own default value when not specified.

Cons:

- It's (somewhat) limited; a table can "only" have 64K of data per row ;-)

**Option #2**

Pros:

- It can hold pretty much any number of options, as many rows as the table can hold.
- It doesn't require an `ALTER TABLE` statement to add or remove options; however, this is hardly an advantage as it would typically be performed by an administrator anyway.

Cons:

- Requires multiple rows to be examined and built into a data structure.
- Fixed value types; each value type requires either a new table or multiple columns per setting.
- No support for default values; you would need to store this meta information separately.

**Alternative**

You could consider using a configuration file instead; keeping this file synchronized across multiple servers can be done with software such as Puppet, Chef, etc.